# How to use MEAN.js along with MySQL?

Tags: mysql, mongodb, mean-stack, intranet

I'm developing an intranet for a company under **MEAN.js**. I was wondering if there's a way to use **MySQL** along with MEAN.js and keep using MongoDB. Primarily I'll use mongo for heavy data, such as pdf's, videos, music, etc. I'll use MySQL for structured data such as users, profiles, statistics info, etc.

The main question is how to do it, and also would like some advices.

Searching i've found [this example](https://github.com/jpotts18/mean-stack-relational) but it supplants MongoDB for MySQL, and i want to use both.

Comment: why don't you use MongoDB for structured data instead of MySQL?

Comment: i don't do it cause i need to relate a lot of data @qm69

Comment: use mongoose.  That will help with data relationships:  http://mongoosejs.com/docs/