# Could I use MySQL and MongoDB under the same MEAN.js App?

Tags: mysql, mongodb, mean-stack

I would like to know how could I setup a mean.js application using MySQL and MongoDB at the same time?, [this code](https://github.com/jpotts18/mean-stack-relational) made an example of how to do a relational mean.js app, he uses sequelize that enables access to MySQL... could I use mongoose and sequelize at same time, if so how, anyone knows about an example?

I've been creating mean apps using node-restful and restangular, but when using MySQL how will I handle the RESTful API?, does sequelize do that?

Comment: People might look this question as duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28868852/4884848), but that one hasnt an answer

Comment: Well fortunately a question cannot be marked as a duplicate of a question with no answer or an answer without any votes ( unless it's your own post asking the same thing of course ). However, people might consider the general topic "too broad" or suggest closure for other reasons. Perhaps if you gave example points of what you want to do then you might be able to avoid that.

Comment: The database you choose to use has zero implications on your ability to create a restful api. The database has nothing to do with it.